# Get text of specific element by ID using $(this) keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several boxes and inside each of the boxes I have different title and headline elements.

I would like to know how I can get the text of the desired element inside the corresponding box that has been clicked, not all of the text elements.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
 box.onclick = function(){
     alert($(this).text());
 };
```

This displays all of the text elements data in the alert box. I would like to solely target a single specified text element that has an id to get the text from it instead.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste an example of that "box"? It's hard to help you with only these lines.

Comment: Or maybe `$(this).find('selctor_here').text()`, but hard to guess the real problem without any html structure shown.

Comment: _that share the same ids_ - `ids` have to be uniqe in html!

Comment: @eisbehr Perfect. That's what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find()` to target the child element:

```js
$('.box').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).find('h3').text())
})
```

```css
.box{
  background: #adadad;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='boxes'>
  <div class='box'>
    <h3>title 1</h3>
    <h4>subtitle 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
    <h3>title 2</h3>
    <h4>subtitle 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class='box'>
    <h3>title 3</h3>
    <h4>subtitle 3</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Find was the function that I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @Jack. I'm glad that's the answer that you're looking for. Happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<div id = "content">
  <div id = "box">
    <p>This is the box content 1 </p>
  </div>
   <div id = "box">
    <p>This is the box content 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('*[id*=box]:visible').each(function(index) {
  $(this).click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Test it here:
https://codepen.io/bmvr/pen/WMZPXW

Comment: @eisbehr don't see any reason to be a bad answer. It works for the question purposes.

Comment: Really? Beside the wired attribute spacing, `ids` have to be unique in `html`. And why do you use the _most exaggerated_ selector you could imagine? And what is `index` for, in your example? And why do you use `each` and then use `click` inside? Seems you have no idea how jQuery works. And even with this many issues, you don't solved the problem of the OP. Your example will result in the exact same output, the initial question wanted to prevent. So, it may _work_ but is completely bad code and has wrong output too. And you _don't see any reason_?! You're welcome.